# DataGrid: Adding DataGridCellInfo-instances to the DataGrid.SelectedCells-collection is very slow

Tags: wpf, linq, datagrid

In a WPF DataGrid, I have tried to select all cells within a given column with the following code

```
for (int i = 0; i < MyDataGrid.Items.Count; i++)
{
    MyDataGrid.SelectedCells.Add(new DataGridCellInfo(MyDataGrid.Items[i], column));
}
```

This piece of code runs extremely slow, though.

`MyDataGrid.Items` is of type `ItemCollection<MyDataStructure>` and holds about 70,000 items.

`MyDataGrid.SelectedCells` is of type `IList<DataGridCellInfo>`.
It takes the loop roughly 30 seconds in all.

Can someone explain why it takes so long?
Also, is it possible to exchange this for a LINQ query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing `SelectedCells/SelectedRows/SelectedColumns` is inefficient anyway when it comes to big sets of data. So you can't change it to work *much* better. Instead I'm suggesting you to use style and `DataTrigger`. To apply this solution you'll have to extend `MyDataStructure` and add `IsSelected` property. Then mimic *selection* by applying specific **style**:

```
<Style x:Key="dataGridSelectableCellStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridCell}}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsItemSelected}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gey"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Property in `MyDataStructure`:

```
    private bool isItemSelected;
    public bool IsItemSelected
    {
        get { return isItemSelected; }
        set
        {
            isItemSelected = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("IsItemSelected");
        }
    }
```

And finally looping through rows:

```
foreach(var item in MyDataGrid.ItemsSource.Cast<MyDataStructure>())
{
    item.IsItemSelected = true;            
}
```

Comment: It seems like this is the best way for me to approach it, thanks.

Comment: I have one other question to this solution:
This works well for selecting a whole LINE, but how about selecting a COLUMN? That would mean selecting one item of `MyDataStructure` per line.